# Errors when dividing with floating point value in C

Tags: c, division

I want to take the the answer from `x_rand / 0,2` and `y_rand / 0,2`, and store the answer rounded down to an integer in the variable `division_x` and `division_y`:

```
double x_rand = drand48();
double y_rand = drand48();
int division_x = x_rand / 0,2;
int division_y = y_rand / 0,2;
```

These are the error messages I get:

```
breakout.c:95:37: error: expected identifier or '('
        int division_x = x_rand / 0,2;
                                    ^
breakout.c:95:37: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        int division_x = x_rand / 0,2;
                                    ^
                                    ;
breakout.c:96:37: error: expected identifier or '('
        int division_y = y_rand / 0,2;
                                    ^
breakout.c:96:37: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        int division_y = y_rand / 0,2;
                                    ^
                                    ;

breakout.c:95:33: error: division by zero is undefined
      [-Werror,-Wdivision-by-zero]
        int division_x = x_rand / 0,2;
                            ^ ~
breakout.c:96:33: error: division by zero is undefined
      [-Werror,-Wdivision-by-zero]
        int division_y = y_rand / 0,2;
```

Someone please explain this to me.

Comment: Write `0.2` instead of `0,2`.

Comment: c only speaks american english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not use European style float representations. You need to use `0.2`, not `0,2`.